# Implement to File Storage Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, controller, frameworks, file-handling

i have a class controller with 2 method (upload, separate). the code run and didnt have any problem. My question is how to implement laravel file storage in my separate method, because in this case I read and write file with `fopen` and `fwrite` not use `Storage::GET` and `Storage::PUT`.

```
    class UploadController extends Controller
{
    public function upload()
    {
        if(Input::hasFile('file')){
            $file = Input::file('file');
            $file->move('storage',$file->getClientOriginalName());
            $this->separate($file->getClientOriginalName());
            return view('layouts.pages.view_upload',['notice'=>$file->getClientOriginalName()." Uploaded"]);    
        }
    }

    public function separate($filename){

        $file_handle = fopen("../storage/app/public/WMLG2_2017_07_11.log", "r");

        //you 'll store your handles here
        $targetHandles = [];

        while (!feof($file_handle))
        {
            $line = fgets($file_handle);
            if (strpos($line, 'root@CLA-0 [WMLG2]  >') !== false)
            {
                $namafileA = explode('> ', $line);
                $namafile = str_replace(' ', '_', $namafileA[1]);
                $filenameExtension = $namafile . ".txt";
                $file = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-_.]/', '', $filenameExtension); // hapus special character kecuali "." dan "_"
            }
            else
            {
                //no $file defined, most likely nothing to write yet
                if (empty($file))
                {
                    continue;
                }

                //if its not open, we'll make them open
                if (empty($targetHandles[$file]))
                {
                $targetHandles[$file] = fopen("../storage/app/public/show_command_file/$file", "a");
                }
                //writing the line to target
                fwrite($targetHandles[$file], $line);
            }
        }

        //you should close your handles every time
        foreach ($targetHandles as $handle)
        {
            fclose($handle);
        }

        fclose($file_handle);

        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a public static function in the controller and add the code there so each time just call the static function in controller methods. Note you can do refactoring in the methods aswell.

```
public function upload(){

     Static::uploadFile();

    return redirect(); //redirect somewhere 
}

public function splitFile($filenane)
{

$filename=request('file');

Static::separateFile($filename);

return redirect(); //redirect somewhere 
}




public static function uploadFile(){

if(Input::hasFile('file')){
            $file = Input::file('file');
            $file->move('storage',$file->getClientOriginalName());
            $this->separate($file->getClientOriginalName());
            return view('layouts.pages.view_upload',['notice'=>$file->getClientOriginalName()." Uploaded"]);    
        }
}

public static function separateFile($filename){

  $file_handle = fopen("../storage/app/public/WMLG2_2017_07_11.log", "r");

        //you 'll store your handles here
        $targetHandles = [];

        while (!feof($file_handle))
        {
            $line = fgets($file_handle);
            if (strpos($line, 'root@CLA-0 [WMLG2]  >') !== false)
            {
                $namafileA = explode('> ', $line);
                $namafile = str_replace(' ', '_', $namafileA[1]);
                $filenameExtension = $namafile . ".txt";
                $file = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-_.]/', '', $filenameExtension); // hapus special character kecuali "." dan "_"
            }
            else
            {
                //no $file defined, most likely nothing to write yet
                if (empty($file))
                {
                    continue;
                }

                //if its not open, we'll make them open
                if (empty($targetHandles[$file]))
                {
                $targetHandles[$file] = fopen("../storage/app/public/show_command_file/$file", "a");
                }
                //writing the line to target
                fwrite($targetHandles[$file], $line);
            }
        }

        //you should close your handles every time
        foreach ($targetHandles as $handle)
        {
            fclose($handle);
        }

        fclose($file_handle);
}
```